# In an HTML page I need to anchor to a tag on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html

```
<a href="#anchor1">
    <img src="http://www.test.com/images/test/test.png" width="80" height="150" />
</a>

<div id="anchor1">...</div>
```

When I mouse over test.png I need it to scroll the page to #anchor1  ..help_me

Comment: "anchor to `#anchor1`"...can you explain what that means?

Comment: I need the page to move to anchor1. Right now when you click the image it goes to anchor1. I now need the page to go to anchor1 when I mouse over the image.

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I edited your question to provide some clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you're using "anchor" in the generally accepted sense.
the  tag is a "anchor" tag that is used to wrap around an image or text link, or *now* virtually any DOM object it consists of either a href tag, which is it's target, or a name tag in which case it IS a target. so a page with

```
<a id="part1"/><h3>part 1</h3></a>
```

and

```
<a href="#part1"><img src="..." onMouseover="$.scrollTo('#part1');"></a>
```

clicking on the image would make the page scroll so that the h3 containing "part1" would be at the top of the page.

to do it with jQuery  and mouseOver you'll need to use [jQuery scrollTo()](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) then you can define your speed and easing.

Comment: I want the same to happen, but with mouse over, not clicking!

Comment: If you're going to use jQuery, inline event handlers are hardly the best approach

Comment: Oh, I understand. Sorry about the confusion. Let me try that.

Answer (score 3):

Use Javascript inside the `onmouseover` event:

`<img onmouseover="window.location.hash = 'anchor1'" />`

Note that you don't use the '#' character.

Also, you are not naming the anchor correctly. It should be:

`<a name="anchor1"` .... instead of href.

Comment: So, you are proposing I do this?:  <a href="#anchor1"><img onmouseover="window.location.hash = 'anchor1'" src="http://www.test.com/images/test/test.png" width="80" height="150" /></a>

Comment: The `<a>` tag in the question is obviously the link so `href` is the correct attribute to use. Also, I'd add the `mouseover` handler to the link (using "link" here instead of "anchor" to avoid confusion) and use `window.location.hash = this.href.substr(1);`

Comment: `href="#anchor1"` should be `name="anchor1"`. Also, to clarify, when you hover over the `img`, you want the browser to scroll to the anchor that is enclosing the image?

Comment: Like this?: <a href="#ani3" onmouseover="window.location.hash = this.href.substr(#ani3);">

Comment: @Evan Pretty sure the OP's anchor tag links to another element with `name` or `id` "anchor1"

Comment: @Will No, my example is to be taken literally

Comment: Oh, I see. I should replace my <div id="ani3"> with <a name ="ani3"><div id="ani3">

Comment: @Will No. Hash links can link to either `<a name="...">` elements or any element with an `id` attribute. Your `<div>` is fine as is